# How to use WITH in an inner query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, with-statement

I have used common table expression in an inner query but it is throwing error Msg 319 near WITH. It asks me to use ; before it, but when I use the ; before WITH, it will throw syntax error. Can anybody help? I am using sql server.

```
insert tb_acct_address
    (
        [acct_key]
        ,[acct_num]
        ,[addr_type_cd]
        ,[addr_line_1]
        ,[addr_line_2]
        ,[addr_line_3]
        ,[city]
        ,[state_province]
        ,[postal_code]
        ,[country_cd]
        ,[address_flag]
        ,[batch_dt]
    )
    select distinct
        [AcctKey]
        ,[AcctNum]
        ,[address_type_cd]
        ,[addr_1]
        ,[addr_2]
        ,[addr_3]
        ,[city]
        ,[state]
        ,[zip]
        ,[country_cd]
        ,[ad_flag]
        ,[batch_dt]
    from
    ( 

    with cte as 

    (

    select distinct
        case
                            WHEN APPLICATION = 'Hogan CIS' AND d.[ACCOUNT PRODUCT   SERVICE CODE] = 'DDA' THEN 'DDA' + '|'+ CAST(d.[ACCOUNT ID] AS VARCHAR)
                            WHEN APPLICATION = 'Hogan CIS' AND d.[ACCOUNT PRODUCT   SERVICE CODE] != 'DDA' THEN 'TDA' +'|'+ CAST(d.[ACCOUNT ID] AS VARCHAR)
                            WHEN APPLICATION = 'CLN' THEN APPLICATION + '|'+ CAST(d.[ACCOUNT ID] AS VARCHAR) + CAST(d.[ACCOUNT NUMBER] AS VARCHAR)
                            WHEN APPLICATION = 'ITF' THEN APPLICATION + '|'+ CAST(d.[CLIENT KEY] AS VARCHAR) + CAST(d.[CLIENT ID] AS VARCHAR)
                            WHEN APPLICATION IN ('RCC','SEC') THEN APPLICATION + '|'+ CAST(d.[ACCOUNT ID] AS VARCHAR)
                            ELSE APPLICATION + '|'+ CAST(d.[ACCOUNT NUMBER] AS VARCHAR) 
                            END  as [AcctKey]
        ,case 

                            WHEN APPLICATION = 'Hogan CIS' AND d.[ACCOUNT PRODUCT   SERVICE CODE] = 'DDA' THEN 'DDA' + '|'+ CAST(d.[ACCOUNT ID] AS VARCHAR)
                            WHEN APPLICATION = 'Hogan CIS' AND d.[ACCOUNT PRODUCT   SERVICE CODE] != 'DDA' THEN 'TDA' +'|'+ CAST(d.[ACCOUNT ID] AS VARCHAR)
                            WHEN APPLICATION = 'CLN' THEN APPLICATION + '|'+ CAST(d.[ACCOUNT ID] AS VARCHAR) + CAST(d.[ACCOUNT NUMBER] AS VARCHAR)
                            WHEN APPLICATION = 'ITF' THEN APPLICATION + '|'+ CAST(d.[CLIENT KEY] AS VARCHAR) + CAST(d.[CLIENT ID] AS VARCHAR)
                            WHEN APPLICATION IN ('RCC','SEC') THEN APPLICATION + '|'+ CAST(d.[ACCOUNT ID] AS VARCHAR)
                            ELSE APPLICATION + '|'+ CAST(d.[ACCOUNT NUMBER] AS VARCHAR) 
                            END as [AcctNum]
        ,case 
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary city]))) > 1 then 'P'
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing city]))) > 1 then 'M'
            else 'S'
            end     as [address_type_cd]
        ,case
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary address line 1])))
                + len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary address line 2])))
                + len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary address line 3]))) 
                + len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary address line 4]))) > 3 
            then ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary address line 1]))
                + ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary address line 2]))
                + ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary address line 3]))
                + ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary address line 4]))
            end     as [addr_1]

        ,case
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing address line 1])))
                + len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing address line 2])))
                + len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing address line 3]))) 
                + len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing address line 4]))) > 3 
            then ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing address line 1]))
                + ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing address line 2]))
                + ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing address line 3]))
                + ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing address line 4]))
            end     as [addr_2]

        ,case
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing address line 1])))
                + len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing address line 2])))
                + len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing address line 3])))
                + len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing address line 4]))) > 3
            then ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing address line 1]))
                + ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing address line 2]))
                + ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing address line 3]))
                + ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing address line 4]))
            end     as [addr_3]

        ,case
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary city]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary city]))
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing city]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing city]))
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing city]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing city]))
            end     as [city]

        ,case
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary state]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary state]))
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing state]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing state]))
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing state]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing state]))
            end     as [state]

        ,case
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary zip]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary zip]))
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing zip]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing zip]))
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing zip]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing zip]))
            end     as [zip]

        ,tb_c.country_cd
        ,getdate()  as [batch_dt]
        ,cast([ACCOUNT NUMBER] as varchar) as ACCOUNT_NUMBER
        ,[MODEL_ACCOUNT_ID] as MODEL_ACCOUNT_ID
    from mtb.dbo.deloitteenrichedfile   d       (nolock)
    left join tb_country                tb_c    (nolock)
        on case 
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary country]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[primary country]))
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing country]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[statement mailing country]))
            when len(ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing country]))) > 1 then ltrim(rtrim(d.[mailing country]))
            end
                = tb_c.country_name
    where d.application != 'RBC'
    )

    select *,dense_rank() over(partition by account_number,address_type_cd order by [model_account_id]) as [ad_flag] from cte


    )AA
```

Comment: Put the CTE in front of the entire query.  CTEs are not supported (in SQL Server) for subqueries.

Comment: `WITH..` is a *statement* prefix, not an *expression* prefix.  So it can only prefix statements, and not expressions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So basically, it is not possible in SQL server. I used the WITH ahead of entire query but then it does not recognize [ad_flag] and gives "Invalid column name error"

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi . . . Your query is (for me) way too complicated to follow.  However, I think `cross apply` might do what you want.